# Can I deserialise a JSON string into an existing object?

Tags: java, json, gson, ibm-cloud, tone-analyzer

I'm using the GSON library to work with data from the Tone Analyzer API (IBM Bluemix)

In my application, I create a `ToneAnalysis` object using a static method as I only need to read the object properties and never create a new instance of it. So I will never need to do this:

`ToneAnalysis ta = new ToneAnalysis();`

The way I'm doing things at the moment are::

```
string json = "{\"document_tone\": { ... } }";
ToneAnalysis ta = ToneAnalysis.fromJsonString(json)
```

This approach means I have ended up with a private parameter-less empty constructor:

```
public class ToneAnalysis {
    private DocumentTone document_tone;

    public DocumentTone getDocumentTone() {
        return this.document_tone;
    }

    public static ToneAnalysis fromJsonString(String json) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, ToneAnalysis.class);
    }

    private ToneAnalysis() {

    }
}
```

Because `fromJson` creates the object via reflection. I am unable to do this:

`this = gson.fromJson(json, ToneAnalysis.class);`

Is there any way to allow a JSON object to be deserialised into an existing object or do I need to rethink my design?

Comment: Serialization in Java uses a public no-arg constructor.  There's probably a bunch of other ways to do this, but they aren't serialization (as the Java runtime defines it)

Comment: Simple:  Just write your own custom JSON parser.

Comment: Jackson may help you to deserialize JSON to Java objects.

Comment: You could use a Gson `InstanceCreator` which returns the existing object, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39953906) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1887).

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to rethink my design?

Not really, because `ToneAnalysis` has no non-`static` `final` fields. When an object has no `final` fields, then you can deserialize JSON into that object like this:

```
public class Foo {
    Object foo, bar, baz, qux, foobar, barfoo;
    public void deserializeJsonIntoThis(String json) {
        Foo deserialized = new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo.class);
        this.foo = deserialized.foo;
        this.bar = deserialized.bar;
        this.baz = deserialized.baz;
        // ... copy other fields from deserialized to this like the above
    }
}
```

In your case, the only field you have to copy is `document_tone`. That means you can deserialize `ToneAnalysis` instances' JSONs into existing `ToneAnalysis` instances with a one-liner!

```
public void deserializeJsonIntoThis(String json) {
    this.document_tone = fromJsonString(json).document_tone;
}
```

Comment: Except this won't work because the ToneAnalysis no-arg constructor is [still] not accessible from `Gson.fromJson`.

Comment: Going to upvote this because it's sort of a step in the right direction.