# GSON equivalent for readerforupdating in Jackson

Tags: jackson, gson

Any GSON equivalent for readerforupdating in Jackson?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.readerForUpdating(obj).readValue("{}");
```

Comment: You could use a Gson `InstanceCreator` which returns the existing object, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39953906) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1887).

Comment: Good, but ObjectMapper can be used for singleton, Gson need registerTypeAdapter in builder so can not be reused. @Marcono1234